# Is there something like AzureServiceTokenProvider for node? Something that can handle multiple authentication mechanisms?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-node-sdk

In C# I can use AzureServiceTokenProvider which allows me to access an Azure Key Vault in a number of ways. If I'm running locally it will use my credentials, if I'm running in Azure it will use MSI, it will look for environment variables, etc. It's really nice, as I don't need to write code to handle running in a variety of environments with different authentication mechanisms.

I can't seem to find something like this for node. It looks like I have to write code to do interactive login, MSI, environment variables, etc. Is there something like AzureServiceTokenProvider for node? Something that handles a variety of auth scenarios?

Comment: Any process now?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm planning to manually do the fallback work.

Comment: With the new Azure SDKs, you can use DefaultAzureCredential, which internally searches for Environment variables, then Managed Identity, then dev tools (VS), then Interactive Browser.  You can read more here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/identity/identity

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`loginWithAppServiceMSI()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/app-service-msi-keyvault-node/) method from ms-rest-azure will autodetect if you're on a WebApp and get the token from the MSI endpoint. Then, the code is simply:

```
    function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
        return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});
    }

    function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
        let keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
        return keyVaultClient.getSecret(KEY_VAULT_URI, 'secret', "");
    }

    getKeyVaultCredentials().then(
        getKeyVaultSecret
    ).then(function (secret){
        console.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        throw (err);
    });
```

If you need a fallback mechanism to allow this code to switch automatically from MSI to another approach, you can test for environment variables:

```
function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
  if (process.env.APPSETTING_WEBSITE_SITE_NAME){
    return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'});
  } else {
    return msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping that there was a built-in mechanism so I didn't need to do all the fallback work.

Comment: It seems that it no have mechanism without fallback.

Answer (score 1):

The older package `azure-keyvault` would require you to use the `ms-rest-azure` package to create the credential/token-provider with no fallback option.

`azure-keyvault` has now been deprecated in favor of the new packages to deal with Keyvault keys, secrets and certificates separately via `@azure/keyvault-keys`, `@azure/keyvault-secrets` and `@azure/keyvault-certificates` respectively.

These packages take credentials from the new `@azure/identity` package. One of the credential is the `DefaultAzureCredential` which has the fallback mechanism you are looking for. See the [readme for @azure/identity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity) for more details